# How to connect remotely with Sybase SQLAnywhere.SAConnection?

Tags: connection-string, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to connect with `.net` to a remote sybase sql anywhere database.

I don't see much info online how to connect, mostly `ODBC` or `DSN` files.

I tried this connection string:

```
Data Source=myserver.com;Port=2638;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypass
```

Which gives the following error

> Invalid connection string. Invalid or missing keyword near 'Port'
>   Parameter name: connectionString

So I tried to include the port with the server, like this:

```
Data Source=myserver.com:2638;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypass
```

Which gives a new error:

> DSN 'myserver:2638' does not exist

So, what is the correct connection string?

PS. Using sybase central, I was able to connect to the database, so it's not a network / firewall / port issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `HOST=myserver.com:2638;uid=myuser;pwd=mypass`. The list of valid connection parameters is [documented here](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sqla170/en/html/81338cc16ce210148a6f92f876460da5.html).

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Now I have a new issue; new question :-)